# ANGULAR: ¿Cómo llamar de la API automáticamente se terminen de llenar los campos requeridos?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, click

ojalá alguién pueda contestarme, necesito ayuda con esto y no puedo resolverlo

Bueno, resulta que tengo un formulario en donde se ingresa un código OTP, que el usuario recibió en su número de celular, cuando termina de ingresar el número de télefono, se debería llamar a la petición de la api que valida si el numero y el otp son los correcto, sin necesidad que el usuario de click en algun botón, si no, que lo hago automático, pero con esto suceden varias cosas:

1. Implemente la libreria `ng-otp-input` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-otp-input) y las desventaja es que como esta recibe un evento click `(onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)"` para obtener lo escrito en los input, en mi lógica, creí que estaría bien hacer la petición de la api que verifica el codigo OTP desde alli.
2. Pero como es un evento click que detecta el valor ingresado en los input la petición se realiza cada vez que se ingresa un numero en el input ya mencionado, lo que hace que se este llamando varias veces a la petición y eso podría hacer algun tipo de trafico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces ¿cuáles son los requerimientos?

1. Que la petición la API se llame automáticamente la petición una vez se termine de llenar los cambios sin la necesidad de realizarlo por medio de un botón que realice la acción

A continuación el código implementado:

Evento Clik de la caja de input que recibe el código

```
 onOtpChange(otp: string) {
    this.otp = otp;
    this.cellPhone = this.bookingService.bookingModel.patient?.phone?.e164Number
    // this.verificado = true;
    if (this.cellPhone && this.otp) {
      this.bookingService.checkOtpCode(this.cellPhone, this.otp).subscribe(res => {
        //Si la respuesta de la api ha salido bien
        if (res) {
          this.verificado = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.dialogRef.close(true);
          }, 2000);
        }
        // else {
        //   this.later = true;
        // }
      })
    }
  }
```

HTML donde se llama el evento click:

```html
<div class="otp">
  <ng-otp-input #ngOtpInput (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" [config]="config"></ng-otp-input>
</div>
```

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda, de verdad necesito si alguien me puede explicar

Comment: Una validación que compruebe el estado de los campos y si cumplen cada uno con las validaciones de formato y demás. Si todo se cumple, enviar la petición

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Al completar la cantidad de digitos requeridos con otp.length == 6
> podes escuchar el cambio solo cuando todos los digitos fueron
> ingresados por ejemplo  vinculamos a un BehaviorSubject pudiendo
> subscribirnos a el en donde sea requerido para disparar la ruta solo
> cuando todos los digitos fueron ingresados

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proyect-tour';
  mensajero: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  otp!: string;
  showOtpComponent = true;
  @ViewChild("ngOtpInput", { static: false }) ngOtpInput: any;
  config = {
    allowNumbersOnly: true,
    length: 6,
    isPasswordInput: false,
    disableAutoFocus: false,
    placeholder: "*",
    inputStyles: {
      width: "30px",
      height: "30px",
    },
  };

  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  this.escucha().subscribe(m=>console.log('code',m));}

  // OTP Code
  onOtpChange(otp:any) {
    this.otp = otp;
    // AL HABER 6 DIGITOS LA VALIDACION ES DISPARADA
    if (otp.length == 6) {
      this.validateOtp();
    }
  }

  setVal(val:any) {
    this.ngOtpInput.setValue(val);
  }

  onConfigChange() {
    this.showOtpComponent = false;
    this.otp = '';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showOtpComponent = true;
    }, 0);
  }
  validateOtp() {
   // el cido completo se emite y podemos subscribirnos a el en          cualquier parte
   console.log(  'this.otp',this.otp);
  this.emite(this.otp)
  }
  public escucha(): Observable<string> {
    return this.mensajero.asObservable();
}
  public emite(msj: string): void {
    this.mensajero.next(msj);
}




}
```

```html
<div>
  <ng-otp-input  (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)"  [config]="config"></ng-otp-input>
    <span *ngIf="otp" class="o-t-p">Entered otp :-{{otp}}</span>
  </div>
```

Otras formas sin usar esa libreria!!

> Con statusChanges en Formularios Reactivos podemos obtener la
> referencia a  controles y suscribirnos a ellos como tambien responder
> a los cambios realizados en todo el formulario y cuando el estado sea
> distinto de INVALID ir a una ruta determinada utilizando desde el
> codigo tanto a  navigateByUrl o navigate con lo cual podes ir a cualquier ruta automaticamente al ser el formulario valido
> [Routing in Angular using Routerlink, Navigate and NavigateByUrl](https://codecompiled.com/routing-in-angular-using-routerlink-navigate-and-navigatebyurl)
> lo anterior para probar la carga automatica de una pagina al completar el formulario en tu caso podes implementar un Provedor de Mensajes que cuando
> statusChanges detecte Valid cualquier metodo o componente conozca a  ese nuevo estado
> [Simple Implementacion de subscribcion a mensajes](https://mariogl.com/como-programar-un-proveedor-de-mensajes-para-angular-con-rxjs/)

```js
BehaviorSubject let bs = new BehaviorSubject('valor-inicial');
```

al cual te subscribis y cuando el formulario sea valido emitir su valor

```js
bs.subscribe(msj => console.log(msj));
```

```js
bs.next('valor');
```

Implementando un metodo publico para cualquiera que se quiera subscribir

```js
public escucha(): Observable<Mensaje> {
        return this.mensajero.asObservable();
    }
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from './user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class ValidarComponent implements OnInit {
  userForm!: FormGroup; 
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,private _router: Router) {
  }
   ngOnInit() {
   this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({ ...validalores.. });
   
   this.handleFormChanges();
  }
    handleFormChanges() {
  this.userForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
       console.log('Form validation status: '+ status);
       if(status!='INVALID'){
         console.log('IR a otra  ruta  cuando status es : '+status)
        this._router.navigate(['select']);
        //this._router.navigateByUrl('/select')
       }
    });
  }
```

```js
<form [formGroup]="userForm" --aqui codigo de validacion..></form>
```

Desde el codigo simplemente hacemos

```js
ngOnInit() {this.handleFormChanges()}
 handleFormChanges() {
 this.userForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
       console.log('Form validation status: '+ status);
       if(status!='INVALID'){
         console.log('IR a otra  ruta  cuando status es : '+status)
        this._router.navigate(['select']);
        //this._router.navigateByUrl('/select')
       }
```

Probe el codigo en un proyecto sin boton submit y funciona perfectamente en este caso me lleva a una ruta del proyecto select que se carga correctamente cuando el formulario tiene a todos sus campos validos mostrando la consola IR a otra  ruta  cuando status es : VALID no te deberia resultar dificil usar este metodo ya que podes ir a cualquier ruta al subscribirte con statusChanges tanto con controles individuales  como utilizando  todo el formulario
[tutorial statusChanges](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/statuschanges-in-angular-forms/)

Comment: Hola! No me había conectado y hasta hoy seguí con este problema, quiero agradecerte el haberme explicado paso a paso el código, realmente lo necesitaba para saber lo que de verdad necesitaba y saber como se implementa. Muchísimas gracia spor haberlo hecho, me salvaste! Utilice la opción sin utilizar la lib, nuevamente gracias!

Comment: me alegro que te fuese util saludos

Comment: @Izlia lo que veo es que en una pregunta que hiciste Como recorrer array de objetos Angular? la dejaste y no comentaste ninguna de las respuestas  una de las respuestas es mia y funciona .Te sugiero revises las respuestas que te dan y no dejes colgadas preguntas en el tiempo yo mismo dude de responderte esta al ver que no revisabas las respuestas a tus preguntas

Comment: ¿De verdad lo hice? Lo lamento mucho, aveces ando con varias cosas a la ves y me pierdo, perdon por haberlo hecho, de ahora en adelante responderé cada respuesta. Te soy sincera la comunidad de Slack me ha ayudado muchisimo y ha sido muy amable. Por eso nuevamente gracias y gracias por el consejo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un formulario reactivo y escuchar los cambios y el estatus para disparar alguna acción.

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  formulario: FormGroup;

  //Para automatizar
  campos = ['valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3', 'valor4'];
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

    // Cada campo se valida por igual
    let validadores = [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(0),
      Validators.max(9),
    ];

    let grupo = {}
    //Creamos todos los campos. Esto es lo mismo por cada uno
    this.campos.forEach(
      (campo) => (grupo[campo] = new FormControl('', validadores))
    );
    // Creamos el grupo. 
    this.formulario = new FormGroup(grupo);

    //Solo un digito por campo
    this.campos.forEach((campo, index) => {
      //Control actual
      let control = this.formulario.get(campo);
      //Revisamos si el control cambia de valor
      control.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        //Si cambia y es mayor que 1 eliminamos
        if (value.length >= 1) {
          control.patchValue(value[0], { emitEvent: false });
          //Enfocamos el siguiente control si es que hay
          if (index < this.campos.length - 1) {
            let siguienteControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(
              '[formcontrolname="' + this.campos[index + 1] + '"]'
            );
            siguienteControl.focus();
          }
        }
      });
    });

    // Escuchamos si el formulario es valido
    this.formulario.statusChanges.subscribe((status) => {
      console.log('status', status);
      if (status === 'VALID') {
        let datos = this.formulario.value;
        //Obtenemos una cadena
        let valores = this.campos.reduce(
          (cadena, campo) => cadena + datos[campo],
          ''
        );
        // Lo enviamos.
        alert('Se manda petición: ' + valores);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Y este sería tu html.

```
<!-- La estructura del formulario -->
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
  <input type="text" formControlName="valor1" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="valor2" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="valor3" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="valor4" />
</form>
```

Te dejo [un ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nmvwqr?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Hola! Pensé que se habia enviado la respuesta, gracias por responderme y perdón por tardar casi dos semanas en responder. Siempre respondes mis preguntas y eso es de mucha ayuda, vengo comenzando en este mundo y aun me cuestan muchas cosas, pero quiero agradecerte de verdad que si. Mil gracoas!